# Formato de fecha en boundfield asp .Net

Tags: c#, .net, date, asp, webforms

En asp .Net webforms en un boundfield tengo puesto `DataFormatString="{0:M}"` y la sálida es `26 de septiembre`.
Me gustaría cambiar esa salida de formato, abreviar el mes y añadir el año y que el resultado sea: **26 de sept. de 2022**

**Actualización:**
En la ayuda oficial [BoundField.DataFormatString](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring?view=netframework-4.8) he encontrado tres formatos, pero ninguno son lo que estoy buscando. Sería una mezcla de estos:

{0:D}
lunes, 15 de junio de 2009

{0:M}
15 de junio

{0:Y}
junio de 2009

**Mi pregunta es se puede combinar de alguna forma estilo {0:d MMM, yyyy}?**

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: En la misma ayuda de la propiedad [BoundField.DataFormatString](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring?view=netframework-4.8) vas a encontrar infornación. ¿la pudiste ver? Intenta realizar el formateo en tu caso seria personalizado o "custom". Y redefine la pregunta mas especifica para ayudarte

Comment: Una pregunta, un formato custom puede usarse directamente en el .aspx en el <asp:BoundField DataField="fecha"   DataFormatString="aquí el formato custom"? Ya que la fecha la recibo de una bbdd directamente.

Comment: He conseguido darle el formato que quiero con javascript pero con BoundField.DataFormatString NO.